# Segfault inside boost::asio::deadline_timer::async_wait

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, segmentation-fault, boost-asio

A segfault gets thrown occasionally when I call `deadline_timer::async_wait` in my method `SendMessageAgain`. It can happen in one of two ways; I've included the backtraces below.  It appears to be random, which makes me think somehow a race condition is involved. I have a class with an `io_service` object `ioService`, and multiple threads that each have timers hooked to `ioService`. Do I perhaps need to lock `ioService` before calling `async_wait`? I thought it handled that though.

Maybe it has something to do with whatever code gets interrupted when the timer ticks. What is the proper way to set up deadline timers when other code is executing as well?

The code I use in `SendMessageAgain` is

```
void Node::SendMessageAgain(unsigned long seqNum) {
  // figure out if and what to send (using object fields)
  if (should_send_again) {
    Send(...);
    timer->expires_from_now(INTERVAL);
    timer->async_wait(bind(&Node::SendMessageAgain, this, seqNum));
  }
}
```

```
#0  0x08060609 in boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >::async_wait<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Node, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<Node*>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned long> > > > (this=0x14, impl=..., handler=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp:170
#1  0x0805e2e7 in boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >::async_wait<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Node, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<Node*>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned long> > > > (this=0x0, impl=..., 
    handler=...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/deadline_timer_service.hpp:135
#2  0x0805bcbb in boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> > >::async_wait<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Node, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<Node*>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned long> > > > (this=0x807fc50, handler=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:435
#3  0x080555a2 in Node::SendMessageAgain (this=0xbfffefdc, seqNum=8)
    at node.cpp:147
```

```
#0  __pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x2f200c4) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:50
#1  0x08056c79 in boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex::lock (this=0x2f200c4)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_mutex.hpp:52
#2  0x0805a036 in boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>::scoped_lock (this=0xbfffeb04, m=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/scoped_lock.hpp:36
#3  0x08061dd0 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::schedule_timer<boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> > (this=0x2f200ac, queue=..., 
    time=..., timer=..., op=0x807fca0)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.hpp:43
#4  0x0806063a in boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >::async_wait<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Node, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<Node*>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned long> > > > (this=0xb6b005fc, impl=..., 
    handler=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp:170
#5  0x0805e2fd in boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >::async_wait<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Node, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<Node*>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned long> > > > (this=0xb6b005e8, 
    impl=..., handler=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/deadline_timer_service.hpp:135
#6  0x0805bcd1 in boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<boost::posix_time::ptime, bo---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
ost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> > >::async_wait<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Node, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<Node*>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned long> > > > (this=0xb6b005a0, handler=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:435
#7  0x080555a7 in Node::SendMessageAgain (this=0xbfffefdc, seqNum=9)
    at node.cpp:148
```

Comment: Is it possible that your `Node` is going out of scope while the asynchronous task is still pending?

Comment: I don't think so. In `main` I do `Node n; n.Create()`. `Create` spawns a couple of threads and then calls `io_service::run()`, which is non-reentrant in my case, since I have a periodic timer and I never cancel it. Could it be problematic that other threads are creating timers on the same `io_service`?

Comment: this sounds like an object lifetime issue, post a [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Nick you can create deadline_timer objects from multiple threads using a single io_service. Have you tried running under valgrind?

Comment: Hmm, I think I may have caught it. If so, it was an object lifetime issue (not Node) brought about by a race condition.

Comment: @Nick please add an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, it's fixed. As Sam suggested, it was an object lifetime issue, though not with `Node`. I had a timer in an object owned by `Node`. There was a race condition in my code where I was resetting the timer outside of the critical section and its owner was being destroyed between end of the critical section and the resetting of the timer. I simply expanded the critical section and that fixed it.

I'm not sure why the segfault manifested itself so far down in `async_wait` though, since the callback (and associated `this` pointer) belonged to `Node`, which still existed.

Answer (score 0):

Bad:

```
timer->async_wait(bind(&Node::SendMessageAgain, this, seqNum, _1));
```

Good:

```
timer->async_wait(bind(&Node::SendMessageAgain, shared_from_this(), seqNum, _1));
```

Have Node extend enable_shared_from_this

```
class Node : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Node>
```

This could fix the issue if it's caused by your Node being destroyed while a callback is still scheduled for it.

Comment: The Node doesn't get destroyed until the program exits.

Comment: using a naked pointer is perfectly acceptable if the object outlives the io_service